# SQL filtering on multiple dates with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm attempting to pull down records that are filtered by two date columns - I need to show all "active" records. Currently, I am able to pull records using the latest "effective date", but the problem is I may have active records across multiple effective dates.

An "active" record is defined as a record with an effective date prior to or equal to current date (see notes for current date assumptions), with an end date that is equal to or greater than current date. An "inactive" record would be the first and second rows of data in my example, an active record would be the third row of data.

I'm working with a data set similar to this:

```
+-------------+----------------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
|  Mode Name  | Effective Date | End Date | Mode ID | Param 1 | Param 2 |
+-------------+----------------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
| Single Mode |       20110102 | 20120313 |       1 | Green   | Metal   |
| Single Mode |       20120314 | 20131122 |       1 | Green   | Wood    |
| Single Mode |       20131123 | 29991231 |       1 | Orange  | Plastic |
| Multi Mode  |       20110102 | 20120313 |       5 | Orange  | Plastic |
| Multi Mode  |       20120314 | 20120501 |       5 | Red     | Metal   |
| Triple Mode |       20120314 | 20120314 |       3 | Blue    | Cloth   |
| Triple Mode |       20120315 | 20131122 |       3 | Red     | Wood    |
| Triple Mode |       20131123 | 20131130 |       3 | Red     | Wood    |
| Triple Mode |       20131201 | 29991231 |       3 | Orange  | Wood    |
| Double Mode |       20131123 | 29991231 |       2 | Green   | Metal   |
| Double Mode |       20131202 | 29991231 |       2 | Brown   | Plastic |
| Quad Mode   |       20131202 | 29991231 |       4 | Black   | Wood    |
| Quad Mode   |       20131203 | 29991231 |       4 | Green   | Plastic |
| Zero Mode   |       20090704 | 29991231 |       0 | Blue    | Cloth   |
+-------------+----------------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
```

What I need to do is query so that each "active" mode is shown, but only the latest active mode as defined by the "effective date" column. "Ended" modes should not be shown. An "ended" mode is defined as having an end date prior to current date - with "29991231" being defined as "no end date". Ideally, the data set above would filter down to this:

```
+-------------+----------------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
|  Mode Name  | Effective Date | End Date | Mode ID | Param 1 | Param 2 |
+-------------+----------------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
| Single Mode |       20131123 | 29991231 |       1 | Orange  | Plastic |
| Triple Mode |       20131201 | 29991231 |       3 | Orange  | Wood    |
| Double Mode |       20131202 | 29991231 |       2 | Brown   | Plastic |
| Quad Mode   |       20131203 | 29991231 |       4 | Green   | Plastic |
| Zero Mode   |       20090704 | 29991231 |       0 | Blue    | Cloth   |
+-------------+----------------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Some notes:

1. Assume "current date" in this example is 2013-12-16.
2. You cannot filter on end date alone - as due to the way our system works, an end date of "29991231" does not guarantee a record is ended. For example, given two records with ending dates of "29991231", the one with the more recent effective date will supercede the one with an older effective date.
3. Some records will not be shown at all because they are ended prior to the current date.
4. This is an old system that is terribly designed. I'm sure there are ton of better ways to store data (believe me, what I'm showing you is NOT the worst part) - but unfortunately I'm stuck with what I have.

Comment: Having read your question, I could not figure out what an active record is.

Comment: Updated with an explanation of what makes a record "active" versus "inactive".

Comment: Working to adapt it to my code right now. The example I provided was fairly simple and to the point. It looks like your idea would work, just need to tweak it a bit. Will report back once I know - thank you!

Comment: BTW I dont know the datatype of your dates so in my sample I assumed it was a varchar, if its int then you need to convert it differently

Comment: You assumed correctly, they are varchar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

```
SELECT        
YourTable.ModeName, 
YourTable.EffectiveDate, 
YourTable.EndDate, 
YourTable.ModeId, 
YourTable.Param1, 
YourTable.Param2
FROM            
YourTable INNER JOIN 
(SELECT        
ModeName, 
MAX(EffectiveDate) AS MaximumEffectiveDate
FROM YourTable AS YourTable_1
WHERE (GETDATE() BETWEEN CONVERT(Date, EffectiveDate, 101) AND CONVERT(Date, EndDate, 101))
GROUP BY ModeName) AS GroupedByMode ON YourTable.ModeName = GroupedByMode.ModeName AND 
YourTable.EffectiveDate = GroupedByMode.MaximumEffectiveDate
```

Just change the `GETDATE()` with the date of your choice

Hopefully this is what you need, I copied your data and tested it to get the same results you have

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE to get the single record for each:

```
with MaxDate as (select
       [Mode Name],
       max([Effective Date]) as mdate
       from
       table1
       group by [Mode Name])

   select
   *
   from
   table1 t1
   inner join
   MaxDate on mdate = [Effective Date]
   and t1.[Mode Name] = MaxDate.[Mode Name]
   where [End Date] = 29991231
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6c43ee/9)

Comment: SOrry, yes, just fixed that.